# Java MSAccess DSN Less

Tags: java, ms-access, jet, dsn

So the problem is that I want to make a connection to a **msaccess database** that has password every time you open it.

- The password works if I directly open the access file.
- I can make the connection if I remove the password, which means my code works if there is no password involve
- The password was set using Set database Password in the database tools
- MS Access 2007(but i used the .mdb)

Here's the code

```
String dbFile = "db.mdb";
String connectionString = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
String driverID = ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true;pwd=qwer}";
if (CONNECTION == null || CONNECTION.isClosed()) {
   dbURL = connectionString + dbFile.trim() + driverID;
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
}

----------------------------------------------
Error Code : java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid password.
----------------------------------------------
```

I already tried adding parameters to the get connection but it did not work.
Please Help :)

Comment: @iDevelop There was a long argument about tags on meta and I think the final conclusion was that it was best keep the ms-access tag for ms-access related questions, even if jet was better, because that is what a person searching in the future is more likely to select. Furthermore, the jet tag annoyed some people and a tag war with Jet/ACE started. It got a bit tedious :)

Comment: Removing MS-ACCESS is tag vandalism. Restored.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 types of passwords for MS Access database files:

1. user passwords
2. database password

With a user password, you supply the user name and password in the connection string.

```
;User Id=admin;Password=;
```

For a database password, you need a different identifier in the connection string to distinguish the password as a database password rather than a user password.

```
;Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

Personally I don't use a database password.  That feature doesn't offer much in the way of security, so it seems like it's more trouble than it's worth.

**Edit**: I don't know if it's possible to supply a database password with an ODBC connection.  All the connection examples I found used OLE DB when including a database password.

```
Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\somepath\\mydb.mdb;" & _
                 "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;", "admin", ""
```

Perhaps it could work to switch from the current Access ODBC driver to the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC.  Or maybe with the current ODBC driver if you switch

```
Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

to

```
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

I don't know.  But seems to me the database password is just getting in your way here.  You already know you can connect if you remove the password from the database.

Comment: I would agree on that one, but this "Database Password=MyDbPassword;" did not work.

Comment: hmm this looks a bit confusing hehe but i'll make something out of it. i tried "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;" but it did not work as well. database connection is my low point hehe thank you for the fast response :)

Comment: Just one last question.. how will i secure my database from someone just opening it and changing stuff, can you point me to a good read? thanks i'll research on OLEDB. for now i only know of putting password on that particular database.

Comment: Do you mean prevent them from modifying the MDB directly with Access?  If compatible with your Java application, remove permissions from the folder where the MDB is stored for those users who shouldn't be allowed to modify the database ... the Java application would have to operate under an account which has permissions on the folder.  Another option for MDB format databases is ULS (Jet user level security); you would need to manage the Access application's users and groups permissions.  But that can be defeated by a sophisticated determined cracker.

Comment: With Access, you can *discourage* the users from doing what you don't want (make it challenging for them), but you can't *prevent* them from doing the wrong things.  If your security requirements are stringent, move the data storage from Access to a more capable server database.

Comment: i will look into this in the morning for now my brain is fried. i can seem to find OLEDB basic tutorials... time for some rest. thank you for the help, much appreciated.